# Find a functional attains its supremum on a closed convex subset of Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis, optimization, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space and $C$ be a convex subset of $X$ which has nonempty interior.
Also $x_0\in\partial C$, a boundary of $C$.

I wanna show there is $f\in X^*$, the dual of $X$, such that $\Vert f\Vert=1$ and $f(x_0)=sup\{f(x):x\in C\}$. My friends advised that a support theorem can be applied but I don't know what is the theorem. Can you help me?

Comment: See [Separation Theorem II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn%E2%80%93Banach_theorem#Hahn.E2.80.93Banach_separation_theorem), you need to work with $\DeclareMathOperator{\int}{int}\int C$ and $x_0$.

Comment: Oh, so support theorem is in fact the separation theorem? T.T

Comment: I don't know. But I think the Separation Theorem is definitely gonna work.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supporting_hyperplane is maybe meant by support theorem. The same should be true in Banach spaces

Comment: Of course, the problem as stated has the trivial solution $f=0$. So you need to require a little bit more in order to make it interesting and useful.

Comment: I added the condition $\Vert f\Vert=1$